# How to get CruiseContol.NET project name from NAnt?

Tags: build, build-process, cruisecontrol.net, nant

Is there a method where I can echo the ccnet project name that executed the NAnt build file within that build file itself? Does my build know what cruise project invoked it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ccnet project name is auto passed to Nant as

> CCNetProject

So in Nant you would do

```
<echo message="The ccnet project name is ${CCNetProject}"/>
```

See here for all the integration parameters passed from ccnet to Nant.

http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Integration_Properties

Answer (score 1):

In the ccnet.config file you would do something like this:

```
<nant>
    <buildFile>myScript.build</buildFile>
    <buildArgs>-D:ccnetProject="$(ccnetProject)"</buildArgs>
</nant>
```

You can access the variable in the build script via ${ccnetProject}. More info can be found [here](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Dynamic+Parameters).